# What is the hostDirectives in angular 2? (directive composition API)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api) says that:

> The directive composition API lets you apply directives to a component's host element from within the component TypeScript class.

But what is the advantage of applying the directive from within the component class instead of simply applying it inside the template? (only to do composition of several directives?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

host directives are particularly usefull if you want that your component always has the directive attached.

Previously you had to repeat that task every time your added the component to a template !

What's also great it that now you can directly add a directive to a lazy loaded component without having to wrap it into another component.